# How to adjust Subview according to different Screen Sizes (Height and Width)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add a view onto the screen using the following code:-

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

let size = CGSize(width: 564.0, height: 783.0)
let host = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.self.width, height: size.self.height))
self.view.addSubview(host)

let particlesLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
particlesLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.self.width, height: size.self.height)

host.layer.addSublayer(particlesLayer)
host.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

But, the view is not able to cover the entire screen on an iPad, but, is able to cover only the size of an iPhone screen. Could anyone please let me know what can I do to resolve this issue? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: what's the size of the parent view (self.view)? generally it's not a good idea to hard code view widths because of different screen sizes. Have you considered using autolayout?

Comment: @newDeveloper Yes, how can I get the size (width and height) for different views?

Comment: I have hard coded for iPhone screen size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below to get device's screen size.

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

However, you should consider using autolayout. It is more clean and useful compare to your approach.